# How to get returned value from js

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have js script on loaded page by cefsharp browser, it is `GetText(args)` and it is return text.
I have this code:

```
var script = chromiumWebBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("GetText", args);
string text = script.ToString();
```

But this dont work, because it is show error on creating script, implicitly typed variable
cant assign void.

Also tryed get value by this code

```
object[] args = new string[0];
var d = chromiumWebBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("GetText", args).Result;
string b = d.ToString();
```

But b returns CefSharp.JavascriptResponse, not text.
How I can get this returned value?

Answer (score 0):

Well, [the docs say `ExecuteScriptAsync` returns `void`](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_ExecuteScriptAsync.htm).

In fact, they say (emphasis mine)

> Execute some Javascript code in the context of this WebBrowser. As the method name implies, **the script will be executed asynchronously, and the method therefore returns before the script has actually been executed.**

so there *can't* be a return value.

You would probably need [`EvaluateScriptAsync`](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_EvaluateScriptAsync_2.htm), which returns a `Task` whose completion you can wait for; you can then read the [`Result`](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_JavascriptResponse_Result.htm) from the `JavascriptResponse` the Task wraps.

Comment: Code now looks like this:
object[] args = new string[0];
var d = chromiumWebBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("GetText", args).Result;
string b = d.ToString();
But b returns CefSharp.JavascriptResponse, not 'text'

Comment: You will need to wait for the `Task` to finish (e.g. with `await` if you're in an async function), then look at the Result in the JavascriptResponse; you're currently only unwrapping the Task.

Comment: Me need to put `chromiumWebBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("GetText", args);` to `Task.Run()`?

Comment: No. `EvaluateScriptAsync` creates a task for you; [you'll just need to wait for it to finish before trying to access the result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-6.0#waiting-for-one-or-more-tasks-to-complete).

Comment: Me need to check with `if` is it completed ?

Comment: Please see the linked documentation on how to wait for task completion.

Comment: Good, me added wait(), but it is still return CefSharp JavascriptResponse.
Code now looks like this : `object[] args = new string[0];var c = chromiumWebBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("GetText", args);c.Wait();
string b = c.Result.ToString();`

Comment: `c.Result.Result.ToString()` to unwrap the Task.